# Python: How to access the elements in a generator object and put them in a Pandas dataframe or in a dictionary?

Tags: python, generator, google-scholar

I am using the `scholarly` module in python to search for a keyword. I am getting back a generator object as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scholarly

search_query = scholarly.search_keyword('Python')
print(next(search_query))

{'_filled': False,
 'affiliation': 'Juelich Center for Neutron Science',
 'citedby': 75900,
 'email': '@fz-juelich.de',
 'id': 'zWxqzzAAAAAJ',
 'interests': ['Physics', 'C++', 'Python'],
 'name': 'Gennady Pospelov',
 'url_picture': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=medium_photo&user=zWxqzzAAAAAJ'}
```

I want to access the element 'citedby' but when I try to do `next(search_query)['citedby']` it returns `TypeError: 'Author' object is not subscriptable`.

My question is how can I access elements in the generator object? and How can I convert that object to a Pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a generator problem. The objects the generator produces are *not dictionaries*.

Granted, the `scholary` library does not help matters by giving the `Author` instances that you are given a dictionary-like string conversion, and not actually documenting what API that class *does* support.

Each of the 'keys' in the `Author` representation is actually an *attribute* on the object:

```
author = next(search_query)
print(author.citedby)
```

You *can* get a dictionary for the object by using the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
author_dict = vars(author)
```

The data doesn't necessarily map to a dataframe directly, though. How would the `interests` list be represented in the dataframe tabular data structure, for example? And you wouldn't want to include the `_filled` internal attribute either (that's a flag to record if `author.fill()` has been called yet).

That said, you could just create a dataframe from the dictionaries by mapping the generator over the `vars` function:

```
search_query = scholarly.search_keyword('Python')
df = pd.DataFrame(map(vars, search_query))
```

and then drop the `_filled` column if necessary, and convert the `interests` column into something a bit more structured, such as separate columns with 0 / 1 values or similar.

Note that this is going to be *slow*, because the `scholarly` library pages through the Google search results sequentially, and the library *deliberately* delays requests with a random sleep interval of 5-10 seconds each time to avoid Google blocking the requests. So you'll have to be patient as the `Python` keyword search easily produces nearly 30 pages of results.