# Retrieving publication info on Scholarly (Python)

Tags: python, google-scholar

The use of scholarly is pretty straightforward to obtain AUTHOR information. (https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/).

Its conversion to a .csv file is pretty well explained in [Python: How to access the elements in a generator object and put them in a Pandas dataframe or in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167543/python-how-to-access-the-elements-in-a-generator-object-and-put-them-in-a-panda)

However, am I am not seeing how I could rather only get PUBLICATION information (Author, Title, Journal, etc.)

Is there a way to that or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Scholarly has a search_pubs method which returns an iterator.

```
search_query = scholarly.search_pubs('Predicting tags for stackoverflow posts')
scholarly.pprint(next(search_query))
```

https://scholarly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#search-pubs